# Robolectric gives type mismatch error when trying to init Activity Android

Tags: android, robolectric

Im trying to init MainActivity instance with help of robolectric. But got an error below.

[image]

Code

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)
class MainActivityTest {

    lateinit var mMainActivity: MainActivity

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        // GIVEN
        val controller = buildActivity(MainActivity::class.java)

        // WHEN
        mMainActivity = buildActivity<MainActivity>(MainActivity::class.java)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`buildActivity` is returning an [`ActivityController`](http://robolectric.org/javadoc/4.3/org/robolectric/android/controller/ActivityController.html), rather than the `Activity` itself.  This allows you to control the `Activity`'s lifecycle via the `start()`, `resume()`, `pause()`, `destroy()`, etc. methods.

In order to get the `Activity` itself, simply call [`get()`](http://robolectric.org/javadoc/4.3/org/robolectric/android/controller/ComponentController.html#get--) on the returned `ActivityController`.

So your code would look like:

```kotlin
import org.robolectric.android.controller.ActivityController
// other imports here

@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)
class MainActivityTest {

    lateinit var mMainActivity: MainActivity
    lateinit var mController: ActivityController<MainActivity>

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        mController = buildActivity(MainActivity::class.java)

        mMainActivity = mController.get()

        // Optional, bring the Activity to whatever state you want
        mController.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Ryan but it does not have an access to the ActivityController how to import it?

Comment: @BorisRuzanov I added the import